# MinilibX : Error When Running "run_tests.sh"

Tags: c

Hello,
Im trying to use the minilibX library but when running run_tests.sh I have this error :

```
run_tests [info] : ./mlx-test running in background, pid: 1738
MinilibX Test Program
=> Local Endian : 0
=> Connection ... !! KO !!
run_tests [error] : Pid [1738] died with status 1
```

Is anyone have a clue of what's wrong ?
Im using Windows subsystem for Linux with Ubuntu 22.04.2

I also try to compile this main

```
int main(void)
{
void *mlx_ptr;
    mlx_ptr = mlx_init();
mlx_destroy_display(mlx_ptr);
free(mlx_ptr);
}
```

and the result was that mlx_init() failed and return NULL.

Comment: I don't know a thing about minilibX, but `free(mlx_ptr);` looks suspicious. `mlx_destroy_display` sounds like it should do any necessary cleanup. What happens if you remove that line?

Comment: If the mlx_init() is returning NULL, it cannot find a display. Since you are usng WLS, i suggest to read this page: https://harm-smits.github.io/42docs/libs/minilibx/getting_started.html